# Folder Size after copy way too big

Tags: windows, xcopy

I have been trying to copy the DESKTOP folder of a User for backup purposes, but once it finishes its way to big.
Source folder size is 21.0GB on properties (55k files)
Destination folder after copy is 579GB on properties (4kk files)

Edit: the disk i'm copying the backup to, is only 500GB size total, and was already used, had 80GB free before copy, so its puzzling how this folder reads that size.

Also, XCOPY when used says "insuficient memory" or something along those lines.
TeraCopy fails, and some other applications fail too.

What could be the reason for this and how can i fix it.

Comment: You can clean out temp folders and garbage can then view with Treesize free application to find what is taking so much on your desktop folder

Comment: Already did a clean up, and its JUST the Desktop folder the one giving me trouble, also, its imposible for it to actually BE 579GB, since the disk I copied it to, has only 500GB total, and its already used, i had 80GB left before copy.

Comment: Does the folder perhaps contain symbolic links or junctions? What filesystem (NTFS, FAT32, ...) are you copying to?

Comment: NTFS to NTFS, yeah, I think it could be links as you and Sunnyskyguy-ee75 say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Try this and see what shows up with hidden files enabled.

I wonder if there are recursive links.

https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/review.shtml

Comment: Shortcut links you mean, how can i track them down and delete them? For testing purposes it would be fine if i did it on the backup copy.

Comment: Not shortcuts but virtual folders. Use  Treesize.  The desktop ought to be  small by putting big folders elsewhere. Then show your results

Comment: AWESOME, this TreeSize tool throws the actual size I expected to see. So there are links messing up with the properties dialog. Well, now comes the issue of
- can i find them? how?
- can I delete them? how? should i?

Comment: I used the NTFSLinksView tool from Nirsoft, but it says there are no symlinks on the desktop or its folders, used the "Search Hardlinks" and "Subfolders Depth: infinite" options. Any other ideas?

Comment: Copy sub folders using Treesize menu

Answer (score 0):

This question is rather old, but I had similar issues with symbolic links pointing to the same parent folder thus creating an endless recursion.

Applications that can not handle symbolic links will keep copying the same folders forever - make sure that is not the case with XCopy or TeraCopy. I stopped using TeraCopy long ago as it was causing some issues and Microsoft fixed the performance of the native copy in the latest Windows versions.

If you need to identify missing disk space try this free [Folder Size](https://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html) tool. It can list all hidden files - even the System Volume Information folder, which you can not access in Windows Explorer

[image: Folder Size Explorer]